# aurelia-dialog error with the release version and CLI

Tags: aurelia-dialog, aurelia

I'm facing a problem when using the new aurelai release :

- I created a new app using : au new myApp
- I installed aurelia-dialog via npm
- When I import aurelia-dialog and try to run the app using

`au run --watch`

I get htis error :

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\src\ai-dialog.js']

Any idea ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because the package is a CommonJS package.

See: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/10

Edit your `aurelia_project/aurelia.json` file from

```
"dependencies": [
    "aurelia-dialog"
]
```

to

```
"dependencies": [
    {
        "name": "aurelia-dialog",
        "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-dialog/dist/amd",
        "main": "aurelia-dialog"
    }
]
```

and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I got into the same issue. I have installed the aurelia dialog using below npm command

```
npm install aurelia-dialog --save
```

then just adding below dependencies to `aurelia.json`, resolved the issue

```
  {
    "name": "aurelia-dialog",
    "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-dialog/dist/amd",
    "main": "aurelia-dialog"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed a little bit since the release of aurelia-dialog 2.0.0.

The block you need to add in the `aurelia.json` dependencies definition is now the following one:

```
"dependencies": [
    {
        "name": "aurelia-dialog",
        "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-dialog/dist/amd",
        "main": "aurelia-dialog",
        "resources": ["**/*.js"]
    }
]
```